# If I used any micro usb cable with an xbox one controller to connect to PC, would it transfer both power and data?

Tags: pc, controllers, xbox-one

I want to buy a dusk shadow Xbox One controller, and I've been thinking about getting the Play and Charge kit for Xbox One, but I heard it doesn't transfer data (and it would be more expensive). Now I heard that I can use any micro USB cable, but I don't know what it actually transfers.

Comment: What kind of data besides controller input do you mean?  By attaching the controller via a USB cable to the PC, it allows you to use it with compatible games, just like on the console.  You won't need batteries either.

Comment: But will it charge it too? Thank you for the answer btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this article](http://support.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-one/accessories/about-play-and-charge-kit) for more information about the subject at hand, but to answer your question, the article states:

> You can also charge your battery by connecting the controller and charge cable to any USB power source, and use other USB-certified cables. However, charging times may vary.

Since attaching it to a USB port on a PC qualifies as "any USB power source," it should still charge.  The light on the charge kit cable will glow an amber color indicating that it is charging.  It may take longer (or perhaps shorter) to charge the battery as well, depending on how much power can flow through the USB port.

As for whether the controller will work, I don't see any reason why it wouldn't.  The article also says:

> Your controller transmits all signals through the cable until it’s unplugged.